# react native fetch API or axios cause Network request failed

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fetch-api

I already checked all the similar problems but none help me and also most of them haven't an accepted answer, also I checked React Native docs but no luck.
here is my code to fetch data from an API:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => { alert(data) })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, []);
```

also I tried `axios`, same result.

No matter what link I use, it always throw me:

> type error: Network request failed .

I want to know what is the cause of this not a hacky way to solve.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or on a simulator?

Comment: @Nostromo On a real device, connected over Wi-Fi and my android version is (4.3)

Comment: Ok, so are you able to reach https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users from your device's browser?

Comment: do you have internet permission setup for android?

Comment: @Nostromo yes. without any problem.

Comment: @WenW I see in some answers that put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`  in  `src\main\AndroidManifest.mxl` file but this permission is already in there by default if that was what you mean.

Comment: maybe try changing the fetch call a little bit. I can't put code here, so I will put in an answer.

Comment: i've removed my answer (suggestion) since it wasn't working.